# Spring Boot, Spring data-jpa detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem where i am creating new object and trying to save it with detached object using Spring data-jpa.

My scenario is a user belong to particular state and that user can change there configuration. If user tried to change the configuration and configuration does not exist, then a new configuration need to created with that state.

But when i try to do that i am getting following error:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.testproj.tester.pojo.EvState
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111)
```

**Efforts**

I have created all the jparepositories here is the code for configuration and state:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ev_layout_configuration")
public class EvConfiguration {
    .....

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private EvState evState;

    ...

}
```

I have also tried cascadeType.ALL.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ev_state")
public class EvState {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence", strategy = "sequence", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "ev_vahan_sequence") })
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "state_tin_code")
    private Integer stateTinCode;

    @Column(name = "state_name")
    private String stateName;

    @Column(name = "state_short_name")
    private String stateShortName;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    .....
}
```

saveConfiguration code

```
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

EvUser evUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getUsername());
evConfiguration = evConfigurationRepository.findByEvState(evUser.getEvState());
System.out.println("============================User from State : " + evUser.getEvState().getStateName()
                    + " =============================");
if (evConfiguration == null) {
    evConfiguration = new EvConfiguration();
    evConfiguration.setState(evUser.getEvState());
    evConfiguration = evConfigurationRepository.save(evConfiguration);
}
```

Please friend help me. I am using spring data-jpa with hibernate and postgres.

Comment: I don't think save method works on detached object it has be merge

Comment: How the session is opened? I guess you don't have a common transaction fro the save code

Comment: can you share the whole method?

Comment: Actually i am not opening any connection or session. It is in spring boot and spring boot managing whole thing.

Comment: Jpa does not provide merge method.

Comment: Do you know if transaction started?, If you are working with Spring MVC application, check that whether you have added <tx:annotation-driven/> in your configuration file

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/07/19/jpa-persist-and-merge/

Comment: @Mandy The JPA API clearly provides `EntityManager.merge`, which is a standard. If instead you're referring to "Spring Data JPA" (!= JPA API) which is not a standard, then maybe THAT does not provide merge, but then it must provide a way of accessing the real JPA API method merge